# Writing Linear Temporal Logic in LaTeX

Tags: math-operators, logic

I am writing some LTL (Linear Temporal Logic) statements in LaTeX and am having issues finding any packages online or information as to this can be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give examples how it should look like?

Comment: this might be a start https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/temporal.sty

Comment: sure something like this                                                           ¬[](critical_section1 ^ critical_section2)

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean Linear Temporal Logic?  Logical temporal logic seems somewhat redundant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some useful symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{tabular}[t]{rl|rl}%
      \verb=\lnot=   & $ \lnot $ & \\
      \verb=\square= & $\square$ & \verb=\lozenge= & $\lozenge$ \\
      \verb=\vee=    & $\vee $   & \verb=\wedge=   & $\wedge$  \\
      \verb=\vdash=  & $\vdash$  & \verb=\models=  & $\models$ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any difference between `\vee`/`\wedge` and `\lor`/`\land`?

Comment: @PeterGrill I think they're aliases of each other.

Answer (score 4):

Applying DRY to A.Ellet's answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\def\x#1{\texttt{\expandafter\string\csname#1\endcsname}&\expandafter$\csname#1\endcsname$}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{rl|rl}%
    \x{lnot}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{none}\\
    \x{square}  & \x{lozenge}\\
    \x{vee}     & \x{wedge}\\
    \x{vdash}   & \x{models}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the [LTLfonts](http://theory.stanford.edu/~matteo/ltlfonts/)
LaTeX package from Stanford, which provides commands and fonts for Linear Temporal Logic.

There is a more recent [ltl](https://github.com/malteschmitz/ltl) LaTeX package (work in progress of this post) supporting both the letter operators F,G,etc. and the symbol operators <>,[], etc. Note that this package includes the previous as an option.

There is the [circle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/circle) package on CTAN, providing an improved symbol for the next operator.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [turnstile](http://ctan.org/pkg/turnstile) package which offers more powerful and flexible options for typesetting turnstiles. (They also have more intuitive command names - more intuitive if you are typesetting logic, that is.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me, using names you know might help when writing formulas - TeX lets you define commands, so you can "map" symbols to words you know :

```
\def\always{\square}
\def\next{\circ}
\def\eventually{\diamond}
\def\and{\wedge}
\def\or{\vee}
\def\until{\mathcal{U}}
```

Which allows you to write stuff like this :

```
\always ( a_0 \implies (( \lnot a_2 \and \lnot a_3 ) \until a_1 ) \or ( \lnot a_2 \and \lnot a_3 ))
```

instead of :

```
\square ( a_0 \implies (( \lnot a_2 \wedge \lnot a_3 ) \mathcal{U} a_1 ) \vee ( \lnot a_2 \wedge \lnot a_3 ))
```

and get the same result :
[image: Formula described above]