# How can I include temporal operators in my text?

Tags: symbols, texstudio

I am preparing a document of my research work so far. I am working with temporal logic. Hence, I need to use temporal operators like next and until. I am unable to do this in Tex Studio. Are there any specific packages for this?

Comment: What is the difference between "temporal logic" symbols and the normal logic symbols such as `\lnot` `\lor`, `\land`.

Comment: It is just that the symbols are not present in an editor such as Tex Studio. Next operator is denoted by a circle and until is denoted by a huge capital U.

Comment: I found a package called temporal. It contains most of the operators. Hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: Where did you find that package? You could write an answer showing its usage. This would by nice for future readers. Thank you.

Comment: It is pretty simple. You can just use it like any other package. \usepackage{temporal} you can install it using the Package Manager.

Comment: See this question [Writing Linear Temporal Logic in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85006/writing-linear-temporal-logic-in-latex)